# How to select disk using Filesystem

Tags: laravel-5

So if I have a controller like this:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {

    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem)
    {
        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }
```

How can I tell Filesystem which disk I want to use?

i.e. this does not work:

```
    public function test()
    {
         $this->filesystem->disk('s3')->doSomething();   
    }
```

but this does:

```
    public function test()
    {
         \Storage::disk('s3')->doSomething();
    }
```

Is there a way to specify which disk I want to use, without using the Facade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I worked it out.

You need to use the Factory contract:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Factory as Filesystem;
```

And that gives you access to the `disk()` method.